# Log REST resource URL using Spring AspectJ

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, aspectj

I am using Spring Boot to develop a REST API and I would like to log the URL of the resources being retrieved by the clients using Spring Aspect. My class for the Aspect have this code:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class Logs {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void allResources() {}

    @Before("allResources()")
    public void apiRequestLog(JoinPoint jp) {    
        LogManager.getLogger(jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()).info("------------------------- o -------------------------");
        String log = jp.getSignature().getName() + " >>>";
        for (Object arg : jp.getArgs()) {
            log += "\n   ARG: " + arg;
        }
        LogManager.getLogger(jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()).info(log);

    }
}
```

I dont know how to pass the RequestMapping object as parameter for the advice, and get the path of the URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can let Spring inject the client's request into your aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class Logs {
   @Autowired(required = false)
   private HttpServletRequest request;
...
```

The original URL called by the client can then be retrieved from that in the before-method via:

```
request.getRequestURL();
```

Comment: why does this work? isn't every http request will create a HttpServletRequest  instance? How can spring autowired different HttpServletRequest  in a singleton Aspect instance?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative without autowiring:

```
@Around("isRestController()")
public Object logApiCall(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
    .getRequest();
    log.debug("{} {} from {}",
    request.getMethod(),
    request.getRequestURI(),
    request.getRemoteAddr());
```